# Formatting CSS with arbitrary elements

Tags: html, css

I can't seem to get my CSS to format my html correctly.

This is what I've got currently, it has copy/paste ability on the blue text, but the formatting is horrible:
http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/29/

This is what I'm trying to get it to look like. The black text is all aligned and of uniform size, I had to abandon this approach because the blue text wasn't selectable (can't copy/paste it) - it was generated content which isn't in the DOM.
http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/11/

The underlying question is, how to position things, like arbitrary `<g>` or `<t>` elements, "above" other arbitrary elements, or maybe there's an alternative way to format this stuff.

Comment: do you mean like so ? http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/30/

Comment: that's a lot better, can the "loves" text be made to align with the other black text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/xa3apsdc/31/

remove `float: left` from `<t>`. Doing so both elements with `display: inline-block` are vertically-aligned by default to the `baseline` value.

---

Result

[image]

Comment: thank you! I learned something :)
"I can accept answer in 5 minutes."